# Windows user impersonation with asp.net core 2 in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am creating a simple asp.net core 2.1 web application which target users are using Windows. I have enabled Windows Authentication when creating the project, and I can get my Windows identity when running the application from VS. But when running from a Linux docker container, the `User.Identity` is of `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` type, which does not contain Windows identity information and cannot be used to impersonate a user.

I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#enable-windows-authentication-with-httpsys-or-weblistener) article, but it did not explicitly say if Windows Authentication is supported in Docker container or not.

## Update

The accepted answer seems to (*not verified*) solve the problem when using a Windows container. However, it does not work for Linux container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this a few months ago. As Docker containers aren't domain joined it is difficult to use Windows Authentication because you need a domain controller to authenticate against.

You can try using Group Managed Service Accounts (GMSA) to relay the authentication for you. Here are some articles around that might help you:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/07/31/getting-iis-win-auth-to-work-in-a-container/

https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/enabling-integrated-windows-authentication-in-windows-docker-container/

Comment: This method only works for Windows container, not Linux container, and it needs a new account to be created, which I cannot do.